# Wrapping `getFileAsync` in a Promise returns a failed result on Word for Mac

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm trying to promisify my calls to the Office JS APIs to allow for the `async`/`await` pattern to make my code cleaner. On Word for Mac (version 16.15), this causes `Office.context.document.getFileAsync` to fail. Is there something I am missing? Here is a simplified sample of how I am wrapping it that fails:

```
function getFile() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Office.context.document.getFileAsync(
            Office.FileType.Compressed,
            { sliceSize: 65536 }, // doesn't matter if this is passed or not
            resolve
        );
    })
}

Word.run(async context => {
    const result = await getFile();
    console.log(result.status); // "failed"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any tool to transpile your code?

If not it may just be that the version of the JS runtime in iOS doesn't support the async/await when the windows one does.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try adding `{ sliceSize: 65536 }` as a second param to getFileAsync() like this:

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 }, resolve);
```

On Mac 64kb is the max for fetching slices, on Windows it can be bigger (like 4mb).

Comment: plus its documented that iOS add-ins are limited to this, the windows/mac supposedly are limited by 4 megs.